# How can I access $(this) element during a plugin configuration to get data() attributes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to configure the [widgetpositioning for bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#widgetpositioning) so that it opens based on whatever value I set in the `data-vertical-position` of the element.

For example, if I have the following html

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2' data-vertical-position="top">
```

I would want the menu to open on the top instead of "auto"

typically one would change where the widget open like so

```
$('.from').datetimepicker({
      widgetPositioning: {
          horizontal: 'auto',
          vertical: 'top'
      }
});
```

However, I want to access `$(this)` object during the configuration so can check to see if the element has `data-vertical-position` value that I should set.  So I am trying to do it like this

```
$('.from').datetimepicker({
      widgetPositioning: {
          horizontal: $(this).data('horizontal-position') || 'auto',
          vertical: $(this).data('vertical-position') || 'auto'
      }
});
```

However, that is not working. `$(this).data('horizontal-position')` seems to be null all the time which set the position to the default `auto`.

Comment: Well it does not look as clean but how about `$('#datetimepicker1').data('horizontal-position') || 'auto'`? Additionally in your exampel code you use `datetimepicker2` and `datetimepicker1` could this be the issue?

Comment: In this example, I used element id. but I am actually using a class name to initialize the widget. I'll update my question

Comment: Doesn't look like the plugin supports this type of "dynamic" positioning. Iterate over the `.from` elements and add the datetime picker by hand (`$(".from").each(function() { $(this).datetimepicker(...); })`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plugin does not support this type of setup, you can do it manually instead

```
$('.from').each(function() {
  var from = $(this);

  from.datetimepicker({
    widgetPositioning: {
      horizontal: from.data('horizontal-position') || 'auto',
      vertical: from.data('vertical-position') || 'auto'
    }
  })
});
```